# How to write ADF dynamic expression with SQL statements in multiple levels

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, expression, oracle-adf

I am trying to write ADF dynamic content for filter activity where I need to filter files, having dates in their name, coming from get metadata activity by multiple conditions. I am writing a SQL query which uses activity output in `WHERE` condition and then provides a DATE as a output. Then I need to select only the files whose date in name is greater or Equals to the SQL query's output DATE.

Again the files which satisfy above condition I need to make sure their extension is either `.csv` or `.zip`.

Basically I have 3 types of filenames like - 'a_01-01-2001.csv','b_01-01-2001.csv','c_01-01-2001.csv'. now same file names also with .zip and .ok(filtered out) for each week. Now these files have dates in their name itself. And I have Control Table in SQLDB which holds last_success_run_date for three of the file(which more likely going to same for all). Now based on this last_success_run_date in SQLDB I have to perform Incremental load on FTP source. So using the SQL statement used above I'm checking if [current Item name] of Filter Activity (Not ForEach) has date in it greaterorequal to last_successful_run_date

For which I am writing the dynamic content but it is resulting in error. I don't understand how to write it properly.

I tried writing this

```
@and(or(endswith(item().name,'.zip'),endswith(item().name,'.csv')),
greaterOrEquals(formatDateTime(substring(item().name,6,10),'yyyy-MM-dd'),
formatDateTime(
select last_success_run_Date from dbo.ADF_Control_Table 
where FileName = '@{substring(replace(item().name,".zip",""),17, sub(length(item().name), 21))}',
'yyyy-MM-dd'
)))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are expecting the Filter activity to query a database. You should put the SQL operation into a previous activity, like Lookup, and capture the "last_success_run_Date" value into a variable. Then you can use that variable in your Filter.

Comment: But we can have different last_success_run_date for each of the file. I have updated my question with few more details. could you please look into it again. for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that in the activity where you're filtering files (probably a ForEach activity with an If Condition inside), you need to use its output.

You can use a variable last_success_run_Date  as a variable or output from a previous activity :

```
@and(
    or(
        endswith(item().name, '.zip'), 
        endswith(item().name, '.csv')
    ),
    greaterOrEquals(
        formatDateTime(substring(item().name, 6, 10), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
        formatDateTime(variables('lastSuccessRunDate'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    )
)
```

---

**Update :**

I think you will need a Lookup Activity that queries your database to retrieve the last_success_run_date:

```
 SELECT last_success_run_date FROM dbo.ADF_Control_Table WHERE FileName = 'your condition here'
```

Then update the expression like below :

```
@and(
    or(
        endswith(item().name, '.zip'), 
        endswith(item().name, '.csv')
    ),
    greaterOrEquals(
        formatDateTime(substring(item().name, indexOf(item().name, '_') + 1, 10), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
        formatDateTime(variables('lastSuccessRunDate'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    )
)
```

Comment: No, I'm not using for each. Basically I have 3 types of filenames like - 'a.csv','b.csv','c.csv'. now same file names just with .zip and .ok(filtered out). Now these files have dates in their name itself. And I have Control Table in SQLDB which holds last_success_run_date for three of the file(which more likely going to same for all). Now based on this last_success_run_date in SQLDB I have to perform Incremental load on FTP source. So using the SQL statement used above I'm checking if [current Item name] of Filter Activity (Not ForEach) has date in it greaterorequal to last_successful_run_date